# jquery click function explanation

Tags: jquery

I can get `$("#demoMapPut").click(function(){ console.log("Success!");});` to work as an event handler in an HTML page.

However if I change it to:

```
$("#demoMapPut").click(onPutMap);

    var onPutMap = function(evt){
        console.log("This is a Test");
    }
```

it doesn't seem to anymore.  Can someone point out if I've done something wrong?  This is just a simple example where I click on an HTML button with `id="demoMapPut"`and a message appears in the console.

Comment: define onPutMap before invocation

Comment: Or change the function definition to `function onPutMap(evt){...` http://stackoverflow.com/a/9423803/1095101

Comment: See [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.  Declare the function before the handler.

```
var onPutMap = function(evt){
  console.log("This is a Test");
}

$("#demoMapPut").click(onPutMap);
```

Now, let's mix in some best practices (and a touch of my OCD).

First, it is good to name your handlers based on *what* they handle.  So not 'onPutMap' but 'onClickMapPut' would be better.  Also, I recommend also using 'on' instead of the click shortcut.  Also, it is good to always use single quotes for string declarations.  So my OCD rewrite looks like this:

```
var onClickDemoMapPut;

onClickDemoMapPut = function ( event ) {
  console.log( 'This is a test' );
}

$( '#demo-map-put' ).on( 'click', onClickDemoMapPut );
```

I know these are all simple, and maybe silly looking, but some can save a lot of time.  For example, look at the handler name 'onClickDemoMapPut': convention tells me *exactly* what to call it.  This helps reduce silly errors and cognitive overhead.

Also, there are x-browser issues surrounding mixed-case class and ID names.  It is wise to use only lower case for these purposes.  Also, the class name has dashes as a form of namespacing and avoiding mixed-case.

Cheers, and good luck!