# Swapping hardcoded arguments for variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I've got a functional script on my site that allows me to open a link in a new window when a specific class is added to the link. I need a lot of those on my site though so I figured I'd make the script a bit easier to edit by working with variables.

In the process of changing out hardcoded strings for variables my script stopped working though. The only one that works is the var where I set the url.

I'm learning that ${} doesn't work everywhere. Hope that someone can point out where my thinking is wrong. Also hope that I got the terminology right, trying to learn though! :-)

```js
 
var function1Name  = "test_function";
var function1Url  = "https://www.google.com"; 
var function1Class  = ".test_function_class"; 
 

function ${function1Name}() {
    window.open(function1Url, "_blank", "height=200");
}

jQuery("${function1Class}").click(function(){
 ${function1Name}()
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Cerbrus !

Comment: 1. `function ${function1Name}()` is not valid syntax. function names must be defined before runtime. 2. String interpolation only works within template literals, so you need to delimit the string with backticks: `\``. **However** it's completely redundant here as you can just use `$(function1Class)`

Comment: 1. Ok, so it's not possible to define the function names in a variable. Thanks, that shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: 2. I've come up with a working script from a lot of Googling and trial and error. I'm a total noob where it comes to Javascript, your answer includes a lot of stuff I need to Google before I understand what you're saying here, haha. But thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: I've added an answer for you which explains the issues and gives you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

None of your uses of `${}` are valid JavaScript syntax.

Your function declaration van be replaced with:

```
window[function1Name] = function () {
    window.open(function1Url, "_blank", "height=200");
}
```

Please note that the function [will no longer be hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423693/javascript-function-definition-syntax) when declared this way, so order of operation matters.

The click handler can be written as follows:

```
jQuery(function1Class).click(function() { // Note that I just used the variable there.
    window[function1Name]();
});
```

There is a `${}` concept in JavaScript, but that is only in template literals:

```js
const myVariable = "Foo";
const message = `myVariable contains: "${myVariable}"!`;
console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several syntax issues here.

Firstly, `function ${function1Name}()` is not valid syntax. Function names must be defined before runtime. If you want to dynamically access a function, place it in an object and set the key with the variable reference.

Secondly, `${function1Name}()` is again not valid syntax. You cannot invoke a function like that dynamically. Referring to the suggestion above, you can access an object dynamically so the first point fixes this problem.

Thirdly, string interpolation only works within [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), so you need to delimit the string with backticks: ``` `` ```. *However* it's completely redundant here as you can just use `$(function1Class)`

With those issues in mind, here's an updated example:

```js
var function1Name = "test_function";
var function1Url = "https://www.google.com";
var function1Class = ".test_function_class";

var funcObj = {
  [function1Name]: function() {
    console.log(`function called, window would open here containing ${function1Url}...`);
    // window.open(function1Url, "_blank", "height=200");
  }
}

$(function1Class).click(function() {
  funcObj[function1Name]()
});

/*
alternative using a template literal, although note that it's redundant here
$(`${function1Class}`).click(function() {
  funcObj[function1Name]()
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="test_function_class">Click me</a>
```

One last thing to note is that no version of IE supports template literals, so be sure of your browser support requirements before using them.

Comment: Yeah, it's *really* hard to format a single backtick in an answer, even using `<code />` doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for this! This should keep me busy for another hour or so :-)

Answer (score 0):

So cool, I got it to work!

```js
var function1Name  = "test_function_1";
var function1Url  = "https://www.google.com"; 
var function1Class  = ".test_function_class1"; 

var function2Name  = "test_function_2";
var function2Url  = "https://www.cnn.com"; 
var function2Class  = ".test_function_class2"; 



// Function 1 
window[function1Name] = function () {
    window.open(function1Url, "_blank", "toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=745");
}

jQuery(function1Class).click(function() { 
    window[function1Name]();
});


// Function 2 
window[function2Name] = function () {
    window.open(function2Url, "_blank", "toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=745");
}

jQuery(function2Class).click(function() { 
    window[function2Name]();
});
```

I can now add a bunch of url's and corresponding classes as was my intention. Super happy about that.

A follow up question though, as I'll have to experiment with what the ideal window parameters will be I'm trying to make those arguments variables as well. I've tried the examples of how to insert a variables output from the functional code but those methods don't work there. Here's that code:

```js
var windowWidth   = 250 
 
var function1Name  = "test_function_1";
var function1Url  = "https://www.google.com"; 
var function1Class  = ".test_function_class1"; 

var function2Name  = "test_function_2";
var function2Url  = "https://www.cnn.com"; 
var function2Class  = ".test_function_class2"; 



// Function 1 
window[function1Name] = function () {
    window.open(function1Url, "_blank", "toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=[windowWidth],height=745");
}

jQuery(function1Class).click(function() { 
    window[function1Name]();
});


// Function 2 
window[function2Name] = function () {
    window.open(function2Url, "_blank", "toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=600,height=745");
}

jQuery(function2Class).click(function() { 
    window[function2Name]();
});
```

How would I insert the variables value (2nd line of Function1) there ?

Comment: Maybe this followup question is better suited in a new topic. I'll create a new question for this.