# Different function declarations

Tags: javascript

I was told that you can declare functions in JavaScript more than 1 way.
ex.

```
// One way
function sqrt(x){
   return x * x;
}

// Second way
var sqrtAlt = function (x){
   return x * x;
}
```

- What is the difference between these two function declarations?
- The output is same but must have a reason to have two ways?
- I am also curious about how you would use them.
- Lastly, are there any other ways?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the second way should be `var sqrtAlt = function(x){ ... }`

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux It was a typo. Fixed. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining

```
function sqrt(x){
   return x * x;
}
```

is that the function name appears in Firebug debugger.

Functions that are declared as

```
var sqrtAlt = function (x){
 return x * x;
 }
```

come up as anonymous.

Also check out this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925976/declaring-functions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

They are basically the same thing, but in the second example you additionally assign the function to a variable. This way of creating a function is very useful when overriding an existing function of some object, let's say:

```
window.alert = function(text)
{
    // Do something ...
};
```

Comment: There is a very important difference: In the first example the function is available at the beginning of the execution context, in the second not until the assignment statement has been executed.